# Pyton2.7 GTK webkit enable hardware acceleration

Tags: python-2.7, raspbian, gtk2

I'm working on some python2.7 widgets for a Digital signage using GTK and webkit and I was wondering How can I enable 2d hardware acceleration?
I'm running Raspbian OS.

```
import gtk
import webkit
import time 

view = webkit.WebView()

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow()

sw.add(view)

time.sleep(4)

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
win.set_default_size(400, 896)

win.set_decorated(0)

win.add(sw)
win.move(1920, 72)

win.show_all()


view.open("http://yahoo.com")
gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python 3.7 webkit2 was the solution, It looks like the WebKit API for python 2.7 is obsolete.